# Equirepartition of sums for large multisets in subsets of finite fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, finite-fields

Let
$p$ be a prime number and let $\mathcal A$ be a subset of $a\leq p$ distinct
elements in $\mathbb F_p$.
We denote by $\mathcal M_k(\mathcal A)$ the set of all ${k+a-1\choose k}$
multisets consisting of $k$ not necessarily distinct elements in $\mathcal A$.

A few dozen random computations (involving various primes $p$ up to $79$ and randomly chosen subsets in $\mathbb F_p$) suggest:

*Conjecture. If $k$ is an integer in  $\lbrace p-a+1,\ldots,p-1\rbrace$ then for any element $s$ in $\mathbb F_p$, there are exactly $\frac{1}{p}{k+a-1\choose k}$ multisets in $\mathcal M_k(\mathcal A)$ with total sum $s$.*

Equivalently, all coefficients of $z^k$ in
$(t-1)\prod_{x\in\mathcal A}\frac{1}{1-zt^x}\pmod{1-t^p}$
are zero if $p-a<k<p$. One can check this
numerically: If $\xi\not=1$ is a $p$-th root of 1, then all coefficients in the series developpement of $\prod_{x\in\mathcal A}\frac{1}{1-z\xi^x}$ of degree $k$ are zero for $p-a<k<p$. (There seems to be a lot of cancellation giving rise to numerical instability. Numerical computations need therefore fairly high accuracy.)

I did also a few examples over finite fields: Given a prime $p$ and a subset $\mathcal A$ of $\mathbb F_p$, one chooses a non-trivial $p$-root $\xi$ of $1$ in $\mathbb F_q$ for $q$ a prime congruent to $1$ modulo $p$. One checks then the result for the series $\prod_{x\in\mathcal A}\frac{1}{1-z\xi^x}$ with coefficients in $\mathbb F_q$. A dozen random examples with $p\leq 500$ gave no counterexample.)

The cases $a=p$ and $a=1$ are trivial. $a=2$ is easy.
The case $a=p-1$ is an exercice.

One should also observe that the range for $k$ is optimal. Binomial coefficients counting $k$-multisets in $\mathcal A$  are no longer divisible by $p$ if $k=p-a$ or if $k=p$.

*Any ideas for a proof?*